# How I access to the data of angular service?

Tags: angular, typescript

This is my angular service.ts code

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    
    export interface Item{
      id : number;
      title: string;
      price: number;
      category: string;
    }
    
    
    
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class CartService {
    
      cartItems : Item[] = [];
    
      constructor() { }
    
      addToCart(products: any[]) {
        this.cartItems.push(products[0]);
      }

     getItems() {
     return this.cartItems;
     }
    }
```

This is the code structure of data passed to the addToCart() function's products[] from home.components.ts

```
products =[{id1:this.id, title1:this.title,price1:this.price,category1:this.category}];
```

How I access this data from another component. I tried like below but it is not working.

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CartService } from '../cart.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-mycart',
  templateUrl: './mycart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mycart.component.css']
})
export class MycartComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private cartService: CartService) { }
  items = this.cartService.getItems();
  ngOnInit(): void {
    alert(this.items[0].title);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `CartService` is a singleton?

Comment: yes, When I pass a string variable to the service. I can retrieve that from other components. But here products[] cannot

Comment: the line `items = this.cartService.getItems();` is never getting executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to modify few things in order to work it properly

**Service.ts**

You can [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) latest values, so that you don't need to use static values(0)  of array.

```
 addToCart(products: any[]) {
     this.cartItems.concat(products);
 }
```

**In component**

Declare and initialize items array first and then assign value like below

```
items: Array<any> = [];

constructor(private cartService: CartService) { }
 
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.items = this.cartService.getItems();
    alert(this.items[0]?.title1);
 }
```

EDIT:

```
products =[{id1:this.id, title1:this.title,price1:this.price,category1:this.category}];
```

You have `title1` as object param but trying get it with `title` key in component.

So you must change the value in either in `Item` interface or in `products` object.

Comment: any reasons for down vote, happy to explain the answer.. ;)

Comment: When I add concat ,  I cannot get output

Comment: when i change addtocart() in the service like below //this.cartItems.push(products[0].title1);// I can retrie that string value of title1

Comment: @NirodhaWickramarathna looks like you have `title1` in products objects rather than `title` where we are trying in component. Also concat will merge the array with previous one so it's almost similar to push with index,

Answer (score 1):

There is no `getItems()` method on `CartService`, so how should `this.cartService.getItems();` work?

You can define `getItems()` on your service:

```
getItems() {
 return this.items;
}
```

or, if `items` is a public member of `CartService` you can just access it like this: `items = this.cartService.items;`

Comment: Ya I added getItems() method. But alert looks like "Undefined"

Comment: You're intialising `cartItems` as en empty array, so before you can access something like `items[0]` you need to be sure you pushed something in that array.

Comment: ya, I pushed data before access  I can see the array has data but cannot retrieve

Comment: You're pushing items with a `title1` property, not `title`. You should access that as `this.items[0].title1`

Comment: Thank you that is the error of my code. Now working :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to call `getItems` in `ngOnInit` ?

```js
constructor(private cartService: CartService) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
  items = this.cartService.getItems();
  alert(this.items[0].title);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried to like this but still alert is undefined. When passing a string I can get that successfully. I think the problem is the array

Comment: when i change addtocart() in the service like below //this.cartItems.push(products[0].title1);// I can retrie that string value of title1